# Binary search on an array using recursion using only three paarmeters

Tags: arrays

So basically I tried constructing a recursive function to implement binary search on a sorted array and although I am well aware of the basic logic that flows behind it, the problem comes in when I only have to pass three arguments to the function which are the array, its size and the item to be searched.  I know that I have to call the function on the upper half of the array if the item lies in the later section of the array and vice versa but how do I do that? do I make two new arrays inside and how do I do that exactly? I am confused really

Comment: whay add the array and its size as different parameters? The size is a property of the array.

Comment: please consider adding tags indicating what programming language you're using/interested in.

Comment: @Dennis, that is assuming they're using a language which provides a size or length.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing this in C/C++ the key is to realize that arrays are passed as pointers. So, each time you call the function recursively, you specify which portion of the array by using pointer arithmetic and a judiciously chosen size.

Answer (score -1):

You can even do it with 2 parameters. here is my pseudocode:

```
find(array, item){
  //base case to return the item if found
  if(array.length == 1 && array[0].equals(item)) {
    return array[0];
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }

  //decide in which half to continue the search
  if(array[array.length/2] >= item) {
    return find(createSubArray(array, 0, array.length/2 -1);
  }
  else {
    return find(createSubArray(array, array.length/2, array.length-1);
  }

  //never reached
  return null;
}
```

This is not protected against empty arrays or null values passed to the method.