# Time-compexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Related to the same topic I have another problem which says to figure out the primality of N. And the algorithm works in such a way that in first step it rules out one third of the numbers, then on the second, it rules out one third of the remaining until I have checked all. So how would I figure out its time complexity? Would it also be of the order of N? I mean in the first step I would have 2/3 numbers remaining. Then on the second I would have 1/3 of 2/3 removed and so on and so forth. But how do I do it actually? I am confused.

Comment: Other posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523398/time-compexity-of-algorithms and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318421/binary-search-on-an-array-using-recursion-using-only-three-paarmeters (since it's not clear what "*the same topic*" is).

Comment: I mean figuring out time complexities of algorithms.

Comment: I would suggest putting the algorithm here since it seems you're not comfortable with the information on your other posts.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.   Time complexity also depends on what operations (how many, what types) are needed for each step.   You therefore need to describe your actual algorithm.

Comment: The algorithm rules out one third of the numbers from {1,2,...,N} to be factors of N in the first step. The algorithm then successively rules out one third of the remaining numbers until all numbers are tested. How much time (in terms of Big-O) will it take to determine if N is a prime number? This is the exact question that I came across. It does not mention the types of operations performed and says that you have been asked to design the algorithm which supposedly performs the way I just stated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you spend constant time O(1) to "rule a number out" the total effort is

```
O(N * (1 + 2/3 + 4/9 + 8/27 + ...))
```

the geometric series converges to 3 so the total effort is O(N).